# A way to save local file after it is edited in Firefox's web-inspector

Tags: html, firefox, editor, web-inspector

I use Firefox Developer Edition to edit local static site (`html`+`css`) with inspector and see what happens as quick as style and content are changed. The editor and debugger are pretty convenient to use. But I cannot find a way to save the file as it is edited.

> Beginer's hint: Use `cmd`+`opt`+`I` to open inspector.

update.
The only thing I can find about changes is
[image]
no "save" button

In address bar:

> file:///Users/kyb/devel/kuvaldini.pro/public/index.html

**upd2.** Style Editor suggests to save a file as by some new path.

Comment: From the Mozilla Firefox Developer Tools:
"You can save any changes you've made to the style sheet to your local computer by clicking the Save button in the bottom-right corner of each sheet's entry in the list."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor#:~:text=You%20can%20save%20any%20changes,sheet%20in%20a%20new%20tab#The_style_sheet_pane

Comment: It suggests to save a file as by some new path.